# Which mean value should I use

Tags: distributions, mean, normal-distribution

I am to test the transformational shifts in three different directions for 3 different imaging techniques in a group of 30 patients. I am trying to prove one is not statistically different to the gold standard. Should I get the mean shift values in each direction for the 270 images OR should I get the mean shift per patient, then the mean of those 30 patients?VERY confused.

If I use the 270 figures I get very good normal distribution on histograms and pp plot, however when finding the average per patient and getting the average of that I am getting the mean of 30 mean figures, and the distribution is no longer normal!

Comment: The question is not clear. It will be helpful if you can show a sample of your data in table format. Will it be like this: PtID, x_modality1, y_mod1, z_mod1, x_mod2, y_mod2, z_mod2, x_mod3, y_mod3, z_mod3. And you want to check if modality1 and modality2 are not inferior to modality3, which is the gold standard?

Comment: yes exactly! do you think i should compare each image in each modality and get the mean of that or get the mean for each patient using each modality and then the mean of the patients mean?!

Comment: x,y and z are the three different directions (ant post, left right and sup inf) the value of x in the new modality is hopefully similar to that of the gold standard. the first modality is doing a simple match on a cone beam ct, the second one is adding an additional step to this match and the third is having a doctor match from the simple match, this being the gold standard

Comment: no theyre different directions so not similar, not sure about variance see my other question

Comment: You can start by plotting boxplot of x from 2 modalities. Also paired t.test between the two. Similar analysis for y and z. Since number is relatively small, nonparametric (Wilcoxan) test may be used.

Comment: u said use t test then non parametric?t test is parametric?

Comment: also what im askin is which mean value should i use?the overall unit or per patient and then mean of tht

Comment: Sorry, but your question and your replies in comments are difficult to follow because of lack of detail and lack of attention to grammar, spelling and punctuation. (You are not texting to friends who can decode easily.)

Comment: See advice at http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated

Comment: I am very sorry for the bad grammar and punctuation. I will make my question a little easier to understand.

Comment: I have 30 patients. each patient has 9 images. I want to compare the image mean translation when system A is used and when system B is used. Should I find the mean of the 270 images all together, or should I find the mean per patient and then add these 30 means and find the overall patient mean, as I have done both and am getting different results.

Comment: In general, it doesn't matter what you average first, as (e.g.) averaging first by sex and then by eye colour should yield the same result as doing it the other way, **provided that you keep track of the frequencies**. If that doesn't work in your case, then either the calculation was wrong or there is something unusual about "image mean translation" (sorry, no idea what that means; in general, people here will **not** be workers in the same part of science as you, just as I can't assume an audience of geographers, which is my field).

Answer (score 1):

In R, following can be done:

For one direction (x):

```
dd = data.frame(ptid=1:len, mod=sample(1:2, len, replace=T), x=sample(10:20, len, replace=T))
head(dd)
  ptid mod  x
1    1   1 20
2    2   2 12
3    3   2 19
4    4   1 13
5    5   1 14
6    6   1 19
```

Code for plotting boxplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd, aes(factor(mod), x))+geom_boxplot()
```

Image:

[image]

Paired t.test etc can be applied after rearranging data as follows:

```
head(dd2)
  ptid x_mod1 x_mod2
1    1    315    311
2    2    288    225
3    3    341    459
4    4    322    272
5    5    223    461
6    6    445    178

t.test(dd2[,2], dd2[,3], paired=T)

        Paired t-test

data:  dd2[, 2] and dd2[, 3]
t = 0.7188, df = 49, p-value = 0.4757
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -27.976  59.136
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                  15.58 


wilcox.test(dd2[,2], dd2[,3], paired=T)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  dd2[, 2] and dd2[, 3]
V = 712.5, p-value = 0.472
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

A paired line plot can also be plotted to see how x values of 2 modalities compare with each other:

[image]